# How to route delete requests in express.route()?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

How do I route to the additional '/:task' part in delete() after '/todo' defined in app.route('/todo')

```
app.route('/todo')
  .get(function(req,res){
      res.render('todo',{todos:data});
   })
   .post(function(req,res){
      data.push(req.body);
      res.json(data);
   })
   .delete('/todo/:task',function(req,res){
      data = data.filter(function(task){
        return task.item.replace(/ /g,'-')!==req.params.task;
      });
      res.json(data);
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean "add and route" Are you asking how to call the delete route from a client, along with the query string parameter??

Comment: I meant route to the extra /:task part after /todo/

Answer (score 0):

`/:task` is the part of the route that accepts a querystring parameter, which is essentially a variable. To route to it, you could do something like this:

```
fetch('/todo/myvalue')
```

Where `myvalue` could be any value you need to send to the server, such as an id for a record you want to delete, or in this case, some task string.

Comment: thank u. I was trying to nest the .delete request just like the .get and .post but I couldn't pass the "/todo/:task" query string as a parameter (opposite to if I had used app.delete('querystring',function()).

Comment: @elL No problem! Please mark this as the correct solution if it helped you out :)